# DocuSignapi - OAuth API call is counted as API request that has limitation of its number

Tags: docusignapi

Is OAuth API call counted as API request? As you know, the number of API request call is limited to 1,000/account/hour. My customer would like to know whether OAuth API call is included into its limit or not. I coudn't find out any information regarding this topic.

Their developing application now can't keep holding access token after an envelope process is completed. It will be fixed later but at present, OAuth API call happens whenever end-user sends an envelope through their application. 
Therefore, they want to confirm this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know offhand if OAuth API calls count against the limit. If they don't currently then they will in the future.

All software stacks for web apps include a `session` storage feature which should be used to store the access token returned from the OAuth process.

In addition, note that your understanding of the API usage limits is not correct. The limit is **1,000 API calls per Integration Key per account per user per hour.**

For example, if Joe and Susan are using the same Integration Key (same application) and they both use the same account on DocuSign then **each** of them can make 1,000 API calls per hour.